# Can Dart generate code at compile time?

Tags: dart, flutter

In Java we can use annotations to generate code automatically at compile time, this feature is amazing for reducing bioler plate code. Many great libraries such as Retrofit, Room and AutoValue use it.

Does Dart have similar features?

Answer (score 3):

Dart indeed allows for code-generation using the same principles.

An examples would be [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable), which generates `fromJSON` constructor and `toJSON` methods for classes inside `yourfile.g.dart`

In general, dart team provided an awesome tooling for code generation. If you want to create your own code generator, feel free to take a look at [source_gen](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen) or simply [build](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build)

Comment: I am curious if it will be possible for Retrofit and others to be ported to Flutter eventually

Comment: Maybe you want [jaguar_http](https://github.com/Jaguar-dart/jaguar_http)

Comment: I am still reading about Flutter, that would be helpful, thanks!